Utilizing the default configuration of tailwind gluestack-ui
im trying to add gluestack to my project, it seems i dont mange to configure it correctly,
i followed the Installation guide (cli and double check with the manuel) but it seems it dosent effact anything,
im trying for exemple to add a button

but it seems those args size="sm" variant="solid" action="primary" dosent have any effact
thats my gluestack-ui.config.json
{ "tailwind": { "config": "tailwind.config.js", "css": "global.css" }, "app": { "entry": "App.tsx", "components": "components/ui" } }

tailwind.config.js:

structure of the project


Make sure that your global.css is imported correctly in the file where you have attached GluestackUIProvider. Also, check if Tailwind has access to the files where you are applying the styles.
You can check it in tailwind.config file of your project


/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./components/**/*.{html,js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./app/**/*.{html,js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
// ..other entries
}




did both even add spacific path to app.tsx (where im doing the test with the button and still nothing), adding those sniiped code to the main question
